# Query dates in Realm Studio

Tags: realm

How can I write query (with date) inside Realm Studio? Query like "scheduleAt != null" works well but something like "scheduleAt > '2018-02-15T09:01:58.146Z'" not. If I represent date in millis it doesn't work to

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've tried with Realm Studio 1.10.0 and it didn't work with that version yet, but downloading the current latest 1.18.4 seems to feature the new Core Query Parser, based on which I have successfully queried it like so:

```
birthday == 2017-1-11@11:0:0
birthday == 2017-01-11@11:00:00

birthday > 2017-01-11@10:00:00 AND birthday < 2017-12-31@10:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

Using latest MongoDB Realm Studio Version 11.2.1 @EpicPandaForce's solution did not work for me. Kinda weird, cause it's also suggested in the [docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/realm-query-language/#date-operators). But I'd like to share a solution to that for you and others.

In my case, Dates are saved in format `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss:nnnZ` (e.g. `2023-01-24T00:00:00.000Z`). Using this query

```
birthday == 2023-01-24T00:00:00
```

or

```
birthday = 2023-01-24T00:00:00
```

deliver both the same dates. So the query must be without nano seconds and time zone information.

Of course you can also use all variations with [logical operations](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/realm-query-language/#logical-operators) to precise your queried data:

```
birthday > 2023-01-24T00:00:00 AND birthday < 2023-01-31T00:00:00
```

Regarding your problem, I assume that your query did not work, because you had the time zone information `Z` and the nanoseconds as suffix on your date query.